# bounds on probability of a product in $\mathbb{Z}_n^\star$ to stay in some interval

Tags: probability, number-theory

Let $n=p\cdot q$ with $p,q$ two distinct odd primes, suppose that they are large enough.

Let $x,y\in(\frac{n}{8},\frac{7n}{8})$ two elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n^\star$.

Can you provide some constant bound on the probability that $x\cdot y\ (\text{mod}\ n)\in(\frac{n}{8},\frac{7n}{8})$?

It seems to me that it is possible to provide a bound which is independent of $n$ but I failed doing so.

Comment: Can you define $\mathbb Z_n^\star$?

Comment: Yes. This is the group of all numbers which are coprime to $n$, i.e. the group of all numbers $1\leq a\leq n$ with $\gcd(a,n)=1$. The group action is multiplication modulu $n$